# How to get the bipartite complement graph in networkx/python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, bipartite, complement

I have bipartite graph and I would like to extract the bipartite complement of this graph. This is the G' graph explained in this link :

https://www.quora.com/Given-a-bipartite-graph-how-can-I-find-its-subgraph-that-is-a-complete-bipartite-graph-and-has-the-most-vertices

I tried to do it in using the complement algorithm of the Networkx library but I got edges between my vertices A and B that shouldn't be connected because in bipartite graph there are no edges between a same group of vertices.

Here is the code that I tried :

```py
from networkx.algorithms.operators.unary import complement

B = bipartite.random_graph(5, 7, 0.2)
B = complement(B)
```

But I have got connections into same group of vertices. Is there a networkx function or Python function that handle it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import networkx as nx
B = nx.bipartite.random_graph(5, 7, 0.2)
G = nx.bipartite.complete_bipartite_graph(5,7)   #or use random_graph with probability 1
H = nx.difference(G,B)
```

This uses [difference](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.difference.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.difference), which returns a graph whose edges are the edges in `G` but not `B`.

---

The problem with what you were doing is that `complement` does not return the bipartite complement, but rather the full complement.  It contains edges between all pairs that were not joined in the original graph.

Comment: Thank you. What if I create a bipartite graph from scratch and I want to convert it into a complete bipartite graph to make the difference ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: you can do the same thing I've shown, with your own steps for creating `B`.  You need to be careful that the node names in your `B` will correspond to the names in `G`.  There are ways to rename the nodes in `G` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

using * helps us to import all the modules from networkx package. We have a function called complement in networkx package, I used it in the code given below.

```
from networkx import *
import networkx as nx
c=nx.complete_bipartite_graph(2,5)
cp=nx.complement(c)
nx.draw(cp)
```